# How safe is it to use an ip for running a Sinatra ruby app for an iOS application

Tags: ios, ruby, amazon-ec2, sinatra, spotify

I am building an iOS app and I have an AWS ec2 instance running a Sinatra app for refreshing and swapping a Spotify SDK access token and I am wondering about any safety issues with having a url such as `http://#someIP:4567` on the application itself.

I know with an AWS ec2 instance you can get it secured by making it a https but how can you secure an IP in the same sense(If I even need to do so)?

Here is what is in the ruby file:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'base64'
require 'encrypted_strings'
require 'json'

set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

CLIENT_ID = ENV['TheClientIDGivenBySpotify']
CLIENT_SECRET = ENV['TheClientSecretGivenBySpotify']
ENCRYPTION_SECRET = ENV['cFJLyifeUJUBFWdHzVbykfDmPHtLKLGzViHW9aHGmyTLD8hGXC']
CLIENT_CALLBACK_URL = ENV['appForSpotify://returnAfterLogin']

SPOTIFY_ACCOUNTS_ENDPOINT = URI.parse("https://accounts.spotify.com")

get '/' do
"Working"    
end

post '/swap' do
    AUTH_HEADER = "Basic " + Base64.strict_encode64(CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET)

    # This call takes a single POST parameter, "code", which
    # it combines with your client ID, secret and callback
    # URL to get an OAuth token from the Spotify Auth Service,
    # which it will pass back to the caller in a JSON payload.

    auth_code = params[:code]

    http = Net::HTTP.new(SPOTIFY_ACCOUNTS_ENDPOINT.host, SPOTIFY_ACCOUNTS_ENDPOINT.port)
    http.use_ssl = true

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/api/token")

    request.add_field("Authorization", AUTH_HEADER)

    request.form_data = {
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
        "redirect_uri" => CLIENT_CALLBACK_URL,
        "code" => auth_code
    }

    response = http.request(request)

    # encrypt the refresh token before forwarding to the client
    if response.code.to_i == 200
        token_data = JSON.parse(response.body)
        refresh_token = token_data["refresh_token"]
        encrypted_token = refresh_token.encrypt(:symmetric, :password => ENCRYPTION_SECRET)
        token_data["refresh_token"] = encrypted_token
        response.body = JSON.dump(token_data)
    end

    status response.code.to_i
    return response.body
end

post '/refresh' do
    AUTH_HEADER = "Basic " + Base64.strict_encode64(CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET)

    # Request a new access token using the POST:ed refresh token

    http = Net::HTTP.new(SPOTIFY_ACCOUNTS_ENDPOINT.host, SPOTIFY_ACCOUNTS_ENDPOINT.port)
    http.use_ssl = true

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/api/token")

    request.add_field("Authorization", AUTH_HEADER)

    encrypted_token = params[:refresh_token]
    refresh_token = encrypted_token.decrypt(:symmetric, :password => ENCRYPTION_SECRET)

    request.form_data = {
        "grant_type" => "refresh_token",
        "refresh_token" => refresh_token
    }

    response = http.request(request)

    status response.code.to_i
    return response.body

end
```

In xcode I would POST to `http://#someIP:4567/swap` or `http://#someIP:4567/refresh`

Is this safe to do? 
Am I handling this correctly?
By having the request being sent to an IP that can be accessible by anyone, am I putting myself and anyone else who is using the application in danger of having their information stolen or viewed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS is only available for domain names. Not available for IP. If you only use IP, then you are exposed to MITM attack and all your data is plain text flying around. Anyone can eavesdrop your request. You have a code parameter in the swap request and I guess is code is credential correct? If yes, it's better to grab some domain name and set it up using aws route53. Then buy some cheap SSL certificate to associate it with the domain. Then on the iOS side, enable HTTPS instead of HTTP to communicate with your server. This has nothing to do with your Sinatra app.

To know more about SSL/HTTPS, you can take a look at some beginner tutorials like this: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ssl-certs-guide/